# How to resolve the issue of the code lines going beyond the code block in the Plate text editor's default code block plugin

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I resolve the issue of the code lines going beyond the code block in the Plate text editor's default code block plugin? I have searched for documentation but haven't found a solution. Any guidance on how to fix this problem?

I have searched for documentation but haven't found a solution. Any guidance on how to fix this problem?